# Visual Studio Crashes when using Crystal Reports Group Editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report in my Visual Studio 2008 ASP.NET project, and when I choose "Group Expert" from the Crystal Reports -> Report menu, Visual Studio crashes / hangs and I have to use Task Manager to close the program.  This happens no matter how many times I try, and oddly enough it seems to work fine on another computer with the same project.

Any help at all in the right direction would be greatly appreciated as I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 SP1, SQL Server 2005 Developer SP2, Windows Vista Enterprise SP1, and the version of Crystal Reports that came with the Visual Studio installation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio and search the bugs for hotfixes. If it hasn't been reported, report the bug with steps to reproduce.

[ StackOverflow isn't the place to report Visual Studio bugs :) ]