# Grouping Expert causes lockup

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I'm working on a report in Visual Studio/Crystal Reports (2005). Whenever the grouping expert is accessed, the development environment locks up. It happens both when I try to open it directly, and when trying to use the design expert for a new report.

I've done many Crystal reports before with out this trouble. The lockup occurs when I revisit an existing report.

I have no idea how to find this error.

Comment: [Looks like it has been happening for at least 5 years][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318348/visual-studio-crashes-when-using-crystal-reports-group-editor

Comment: I did a "repair" (i.e. reinstall) from VS. No change.

Answer (score 0):

The cause turned out to be that the Expert dialog box had been moved to a second screen on a previous occasion. Once I discovered that, it was easy to move it back into view. (Alt-Space, choose Move, move it with arrow keys.)

I found the solution on a Microsoft Q/A site using Bing. Not surprisingly, I find Bing has better coverage of MS data than Google.